# Why use the + sign in printfl?

Tags: go

What's the difference between:

```
var x float64 = 3.141592
fmt.Println("the value is" + x)
```

and

```
var x float64 = 3.141592
fmt.Println("the value is", x)
```

What does the `+` means?

Why is the first one wrong and the second correct?

Comment: The `+` sign doesn't mean anything, it's not valid to add a `string` and a `float64`.

Comment: So why using it? I'm watching an online course that the instructor writes fmt.Println("the value is" + x) and fmt.Printfl("the value is" +xs) (xs is a string)

Comment: Yes, you can concatenate strings, but `x` in your example isn’t a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fmt.Println](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println) is a variadic function whose arguments are generic interfaces.  Any type can fulfill this interfere, including strings and floats.  The second example works for this reason.

The first example, however, involves the binary operator `+`.  As https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators says, binary operators work in identical types.  This means you can't "add" a float to a string without first explicitly casting to a string.

In general, this is a decision the golang inventors made. If you read the design tenets of go, I think you'll find this aligns well.  But for the purposes of your question, it's sufficient to say, that's how it was made to work.

Comment: So, it does not work because I'm trying to add a float to a string

But can I omit +? For example:

        x := 3.141592

 fmt.Println("the value is", x)

 xs := fmt.Sprint(x)

 fmt.Println("the value is " + xs)

 fmt.Println("the value is", xs)

Both ways are right?

Comment: @leoperassoli for the second case. Why not just use fmt.Printf(“the value is %v“, x)

Comment: Yes, it makes more sense. But, I want to know why the instructor is using +

Comment: @leoperassoli None of the people here actually know the exact intentions of your instructor; but what matters is that when your instructor used the `+`, he meant to concatenate the 2 strings and then pass the result of the concatenation as the first (and sole) argument of `fmt.Println`. In *your* example, you are trying to use the `+` operator for two values of different type, which is plain wrong in Go. When you use the `,` instead, you actually pass **two** arguments to `fmt.Println`, which is perfectly valid according to the definition of `fmt.Println`, hence it works fine.